# What happened to the Piled Higher and Deeper comics?

Tags: academic-life, social-media

Without dating myself too badly, I have enjoyed [PhD comics](http://phdcomics.com/comics.php) since the beginning. For the past few years, there have been about 2 or 3 new comics a week, but there has not been a new comic in months. I don't really follow all their social media contacts, but it does not look like there has been a tweet or a facebook update in a while.

Was there any announcement about a break (or the end)?

Comment: Odd to see such an obviously off topic question from a mod. You know about the chat rooms, of course.

Comment: Maybe you could ask them by e-mail? As it now stands, it looks rather off-topic to me.

Comment: @Buffy why is it off topic? If Google scholar or pubmed went down, or had a major unannounced change, wouldn't that be on topic? Something like XKCD comics has a non-academic following, but my guess is PhD Comics is more or less only followed by academics.

Comment: So the close vote must be from a NON Fan... Got to be better than a "I want..." question...

Comment: I would not consider it off-topic, since it is clearly related to academics. It is just hard to answer, as Guest already has indicated. Maybe Jorge Cham has run out of ideas and is looking for our contributions?! I guess some of the funny to bizarre situations we encounter in academics are worth telling.

Comment: Don't know what caused the break, so won't write a full answer, but: (1) I saw Jorge speak live several years ago and he confirmed that the last strip will reveal the protagonist's name. So probably not the end, assuming he is still alive and well. (2) I think the 2-3 per week frequency has not been true for several years now, more like 1-2 per month. Most likely because he has been more active in his "explaining science" endeavors (sigh). But I agree it has been ~3 months since the last one, which is unusually long.

Comment: @cag51 the dates are all listed [here](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive_list.php) and you are correct that 2-3 a week is way too high of an estimate. Last one was [11/23/18](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=2031)

Comment: One of the stretch goals in last year's kickstarter campaign (which was successfully reached) was that one of the main characters would graduate ("the storyline will complete before the end of the year"). This obviously has not happened so far.

Comment: The problem with this being adjudged on-topic is, it will act as a precedent for similar _me-toos_, and even more so because the OP is a mod. Also, unless somebody gets a horse's mouth account (i.e. from Jorge himself), any other answer is essentially speculative.

Comment: Alas, [1060nm](https://web.archive.org/web/20161008161810/http://1060nm.com/1/en/), you went offline far too soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He took a [break](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=2032), but the comics are [back now](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=2034).

Answer (score 18):

According to [the latest comic](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=2032), the series is on hiatus until November 2019. The unsubtle message behind the comic is that the author doesn't owe an explanation to anyone.

Comment: Just to be clear I wasn't asking for justification or even an explanation, but was just looking for the email Prof Smith sent. I still haven't recovered from losing homestar.

Comment: When was this comic published, just a couple of days ago, right? I'm going to assume there's a mistake in PhD comics archive http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive_list.php (since I don't remember that comic being there last year) and it was actually published 6th May 2019? (and apparently the author feels like he does owe his readers an explanation, despite the message the comic is trying to send -- seeing as he published this "explanatory" comic more than 6 months after stopping other activities).

Answer (score 9):

Not sure what happened with PhD comics, but Jorge Cham seems to be actively involved in this other project: https://www.danielandjorge.com/
It looks like the last comics were around the time of his Kickstarted book celebrating 20 years of PhD comics.  Maybe he got burned out by that endeavour?

Comment: I noticed that a lot of the more recent comics were credited to someone else, as sort of "thanks to ___ for this idea!" - the comic's been around a long time, might be running out of creative novelty.

Comment: +1 -- following that link shows that this other project is putting out 2-3 updates a week. I suspect he just doesn't have enough bandwidth for both, so the frequency of the comics has fallen off (though you'd think there would be a note).